# Can't login using OpenId (core) and Google profile

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization

I'm using the OpenId module (included in core v7) but can't link an OpenId to an existing account. Every time I try to add it an error occurs:

> Sorry, that is not a valid OpenID. Ensure you have spelled your ID
>   correctly.

I'm trying to connect using a Google profile. The URL I'm trying is "https://profiles.google.com/x" (x => my id).

Has anybody succeeded in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in Drupal 7:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
```

For more information, see [Whats My Google OpenID URL?](http://lenni.info/blog/2009/12/whats-my-google-openid-url/).

Comment: "Sorry, that is not a valid OpenID. Ensure you have spelled your ID correctly." :-(

Comment: Any chance you have a trailing space or something? I tested the URL before I posted it and it worked for me.